# Create interface wrapping existing types with pointer-receiver methods

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I need to test an app which uses Google Cloud Pubsub, and so must wrap its types `pubsub.Client` and `pubsub.Subscriber` for testing purposes. However, despite several attempts I can't get an interface around them which compiles.

The definitions of the methods I'm trying to wrap are:

```
func (s *Subscription) Receive(
    ctx context.Context, f func(context.Context, *Message)) error

func (c *Client) Subscription(id string) *Subscription
```

Here is the current code. The `Receiver` interface (wrapper around `Subscriber`) seems to work, but I suspect it may need to change in order to fix `SubscriptionMaker`, so I've include both.

Note: I've tried several variations of where to reference and dereference pointers, so please don't tell me to change that unless you have an explanation of why your suggested configuration is the correct one or you've personally verified it compiles.

```golang
import (
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

type Receiver interface {
    Receive(context.Context, func(ctx context.Context, msg *pubsub.Message)) (err error)
}

// Pubsub subscriptions implement Receiver
var _ Receiver = &pubsub.Subscription{}

type SubscriptionMaker interface {
    Subscription(name string) (s Receiver)
}

// Pubsub clients implement SubscriptionMaker
var _ SubscriptionMaker = pubsub.Client{}
```

Current error message:

```
common_types.go:21:5: cannot use "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub".Client literal (type "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub".Client) as type SubscriptionMaker in assignment:
    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub".Client does not implement SubscriptionMaker (wrong type for Subscription method)
        have Subscription(string) *"cloud.google.com/go/pubsub".Subscription
        want Subscription(string) Receiver
```

Comment: The `Subscription` function is defined to return `*Subscription`, but in your interface it returns `Receiver`. The types must be the same. It doesn't matter that `*Subscription` implements the `Receiver` interface. The types must match exactly.

Comment: So it's impossible to do this, then?

Comment: If you define `Subscription` in your interface to return `*pubiub.Subscription` it will work.

Comment: That wouldn't accomplish the goal of making this be mockable for testing purposes. So it's impossible.

Comment: You can accomplish this, but it requires using custom-defined types that wrap all returned types. So you'd have to create a new type that wraps `*pubsub.Subscription`, and use that throughout your app, and a custom wrapper even for your non-test code. Yes, that's a big pain. It's often not worth it.

Comment: No, I cannot do that. This is a library function; I have no ability to modify the return type of `Client.Subscription`.

Comment: I know it's a library function. That's why I said you need to wrap the function and the type. Specifically, you need to wrap the `Client` type here. See my answer below for better elaboration on what I mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can't be done.

When defining the type signature of a method on an interface, it must match exactly. `func (c *Client) Subscription(id string) *Subscription` returns a `*Subscription`, and a `*Subscription` is a valid `Receiver`, but it does not count as conforming to the interface method `Subscription(string) Receiver`. Go requires precise matching for function signatures, not the duck-typing style that it usually uses for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

First, for most uses, using the [`ptest`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub/pstest) package is probably a much easier approach for testing pubsub.  But of course, your specific question can apply to any library, and the below approach can be useful for many things, not just mocking `pubsub`.

---

Your broader goal of using interfaces to mock a library like this, is doable. But it is complicated when the library you wish to mock out returns concrete types that you cannot mock (probably due to unreported fields). The approach to be taken is much more involved than is often worth it, as there may be easier ways to test your code.

But if you're intent on doing this, the approach you must take is to not wrap the entire package in interfaces, not just the specific methods you wish to mock.

You would need to wrap any types that you wish to mock which are returned by or accepted by your interface, too.  This usually means you also need to modify your production code (not just your test code), so this can sometimes be a deal-breaker for existing code bases.

Where I have usually done this before is when mocking something like the standard library's sql driver, but the same approach can be applied here. In essence, you would need to create a wrapper package for your `pubsub` library, which you use even in your production code. Again, this can be quite intrusive on existing codebases, but for the sake of illustration. Using your defined interfaces:

```
package mypubsub

import "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"

type Receiver interface {
    Recieve(context.Context, func(context.Context, *pubsub.Message) error)
}

type SubscriptionMaker interface {
    Subscription(string) Receiver
}
```

You can then wrap the default implementation, for use in production code:

```
// defaultClient wraps the default pubsub Client functionality.
type defaultClient struct {
    *pubsub.Client
}

func (d defaultImplementation) Subscription(name string) Receiver {
    return d.Client.Subscription()
}
```

Naturally, you'd need to expand this package to wrap most or all of the `pubsub` package you're using. This can be a bit daunting.

But once you've done that, then use your `mypubsub` package everywhere in your code, instead of directly depending on the `pubsub` package. And now you can easily swap out a mock implementation anywhere you need for testing.